# Bash: include formatted date to a rename regex

Tags: regex, bash, rename

I have a script that monitors a set of folder names from a list ($docs).
And if it finds a **not empty** folder, it should: rename and move files and append a timestamp it.

This is what I got so far:

```
docs="/home/user/docs.txt"

cat $docs | while read line
do
if find "$line" -mindepth 1 -print-quit | grep -q .; then
   find $line -type f | rename 's:(^|.*/)([^/]*)/([^/]*)$:/tmp/$2$3
else
   echo "empty folders" $line
fi
done
```

the file docs.txt is a set of folders listed like this:

```
/foldername
/anotherfoldername
```

This script renames my files correctly (folderplacement_filename.ext), and moves them to the /temp/ directory.

But the challenge is appending a "date +%d%m%Y%H%M%S" string, and I can not find any way to gracefully add this to my rename string.

Adding a $(date), ignores any extra formating.

For example Appending it to rename 's:(^|.*/)([^/]*)/([^/]*)$:/tmp/$2$3$(date)
gives a filename like "folderplacement_filename.ext 4 24 35 20 48 111 123 321"

I want the file to look like "folderplacement_filename11102017011632.ext" (appending the date after the .ext is also ok.)

This is probably something I need to quote or bracket in the right way, but I can not figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no experience with rename, but I would suggest that there is a quote missing at the end of that line.

If you are using single quotes, the shell does not expand variables for you. That means that the last part of the command argument is actually `$(date)`, which is not what you want. You could use double quotes, but that would mean that you need to escape all the `$` with backslashes. Or you could put the date part outside the single quotes, as in

```
now=$(date +%d%m%Y%H%M%S)
find $line -type f | rename 's:(^|.*/)([^/]*)/([^/]*)$:/tmp/$2$3'$now
```

Comment: Thank you! This put me on the right track. I solved it by double quoting and escaping the $'es: rename "s:(^|.*/)([^/]*)([^/]*)/([^/]*)\$:/tmp/$now\_\$2\$3\$4:"  You are also correct in spotting the missing ', that was a typo not found in the script.